# Make Gitlab warn devs of breaking changes upon git pull/clone/checkout

Tags: git, gitlab, hook

I've been looking for a way to warn a developer on a repo of breaking changes upon a git pull or a git clone or a git checkout (either one would be fine to begin with). Example:

`$ git pull --rebase origin XXX
remote: Counting objects: 67, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (50/50), done.
remote: Total 67 (delta 20), reused 46 (delta 10)
Unpacking objects: 100% (67/67), done.
[...]
Warning: usage has changed for this project. Please read the release note: xxxx`

Is there a way to do that based on release notes in tags, or through a CHANGELOG.md versioned file?

Any input would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: You might be able to hook into `post-merge`, but the specifics depend on what you want to be doing. Git has no notion of "breaking changes" or of a linear version of a working directory, and a hook is an arbitrary executable - you'll have to implement remembering the previous version and reading the changelog to find out the difference yourself.

Comment: @millimoose I ended up making a post-merge git hook that does a git diff, works like a charm! Thanks :)